# How can I present UIImagePickerViewController in UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]

Is it possible for developers, or is it private library used by Apple only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a private API. There's no support for it even in the new `UIAlertController`, which replaces the `UIActionSheet`.